# Can't get Redux (Thunks) to work with NextJS using next-redux-wrapper: getInitalProps not called

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get Redux to work with thunks using next-redux-wrapper. I've looked at the example code but my code doesn't work. I've gone back and forth and no longer see the forest for the trees. At the moment my 'getInitialProps' in index.js isn't being called, hence my data is never loaded because I never dispatch the dataloading action.  The store is created, but it's empty.

```
// _app.js
import {createStore} from "redux";
import {Provider} from "react-redux";
import App from "next/app";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import initStore from '../redux/store'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps,store }) {
    console.log('in _app', store.getState())
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
export default withRedux(initStore,{debug:true})(MyApp);



// store.js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './root-reducer'
const store = () => configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
})
export default store



// index.js
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Nav from '../components/nav'
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import {fetchPosts} from '../redux/posts'
const Home = () => {
 return  (<div>
    <Head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    </Head>
    <Nav />
    <div className="hero">
      <h1 className="title">Welcome YAA!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>)
}
Home.getInitialProps = async ({store,isServer}) => {
    console.log('about to dispatch')
    store.dispatch(fetchPosts())
    return {store,isServer}
}
export default Home
```

### Edit

This worked.  I suppose it has to be a class, although the [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper/pages/_app.js) on the NextJS site uses a functional component

```
import App from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import initStore from '../redux/store'

const makeStore = (initialState, options) => {
    return initStore(initialState)
};
class MyApp extends App {

static async getInitialProps({Component, ctx}) {


        const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};

        return {pageProps};

    }

    render() {
        // @ts-ignore
      const {Component, pageProps, store} = this.props;
        return (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Provider>
        );
    }

}

export default withRedux(makeStore)(MyApp);
```

Comment: can you call it with a functional component? didn't think that was possible

Comment: @JoeLloyd, using a class seems to work.  But the example on the NextJS site uses a functional component  -- https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-redux-wrapper/pages/_app.js

Comment: The example you linked does not use `getInitialProps`.
pretty sure its only usable in a class.

Comment: @JoeLloyd --   when you say "it's only usable in a class", I don't know what 'it' is.  You seem to be right that one can only get next-redux-wrapper to work if you write `/page/_app.js` using classes.  As per my edit above.  I assume that's what you mean -- do you know why it's so?

Comment: @JoeLloyd -- you can use `getInitalProps`with functional components, see https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps -- or perhaps I'm misunderstanding you...

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue as you and after reading the comments here and with your solution to your problem, I rewrote what I had as funcional component and it's working so if you wanna use or for anyone having the same issue, here's a solution:

```js
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { initStore } from "../store/store";

import "./styles.scss";

const MyApp = props => {
  const { Component, pageProps, store } = props;
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
    ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    : {};
  return { pageProps };
};

export default withRedux(initStore)(MyApp);
```

Comment: Why you use `next-redux-wrapper` and `<Provider>` at the same time?

Comment: You [don't need](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-thunk) `next-redux-wrapper` if you're using `Redux-Thunk`

Comment: What if you want to dispatch an action from _app.js getInitialProps - how could you access the store to dispatch it?

Comment: I wrote this. You can look into this example. It has done the same thing.
https://github.com/fazlulkarimweb/with-next-redux-wrapper-redux-persist .